# How to reset the position of a moving image in vb.net when the number 0 is pressed

Tags: vb.net

I need to make a moving picture (the copter) in a visual basic form return to the position above the landing pad label every time I hit the 0 but taking into consideration the size of the form.
I tried setting the location to that position but if the user maximizes the window then the x and y coordinates change and I don't know how to code it so it returns to its landing position and adjust it to the forms position.
thanks for your help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvyLQ.jpgT

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried. We are not a coding service, we help with specific issues. Not showing anything you have tried makes us assume you have not tried anything for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your copter is a `PictureBox` and you want it in the middle at the bottom:

```
Dim clientSize = Me.ClientSize
Dim x = (clientSize.Width - PictureBox1.Width) \ 2
Dim y = clientSize.Height - PictureBox1.Height

PictureBox1.Location = New Point(x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, you just need to do the following:

```
Public Sub CallMeWhenTheyPressZero()
    Dim dCenterX As Double = Form1.Size.Width/2
    Dim iBottomY As Integer = 10 ' I am going to assume this never changes. (Bottom bar never resizes vertically.)
    Dim dHalfCopterX As Double = CopterPictureBox.Size.Width/2
    Dim iLeftDifference As Integer = System.Math.Round(dCenterX-dHalfCopterY)

    ' Do the center
    CopterPictureBox.Left = iLeftDifference
    CopterPictureBox.Bottom = iBottomY
End Sub
```

It has been a long time since I have written code in VB.net, so my apologies if there are any errors. However, the fundamental idea is what is important.